# counterup timer onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, onclick, counter

I have a count-up script, I put it in a modal, I added onclick event to the trigger, but my problem is that the counter start working when page is loaded. When I opened the modal popup after 30 sec, the counter showed 30 sec... I want it to start from 0 when modal pop-up is being opened
I have as below
trigger

```js
var count1=0; 
var counter1=setInterval(myTimerUp, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
function myTimerUp()
{
  count1=count1+1;
  if (count1 == 100)
  {
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById("timerUp").innerHTML="This pop-up is running from "+ count1 + " secs"; // watch for spelling
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exModal1button" onclick="myTimerUp()">Pop-up manual trigger </button>
<span id="timerUp"></span>
```

Comment: please cultivate habit of adding snippet.

Comment: @RajkumarSomasundaram added the snippet

Answer (score 0):

You call `setInterval` at the beginning of your script, so the counter starts to increment from the beginning.

You must set it at the first call of the function.

```
var count1=0; 
var counter1;
function myTimerUp()
{
  //Start the setInterval only on the first time myTimerUp is run.
  if(!counter1) {
     counter1 = setInterval(myTimerUp, 1000); //1000 will run it every 1 second
  }
  count1=count1+1;
  if (count1 == 100)
  {
     clearInterval(counter1);
     return;
  }

 document.getElementById("timerUp").innerHTML="This pop-up is running from "+ count1 + " secs"; // watch for spelling
}
```

Plus, watchout: i've fixed a typo on your original code: `clearInterval(counter)` becomes `clearInterval(counter1)`: there is no `counter` variable defined.

Answer (score 0):

I have tweaked your code a little, to make it work

I am invoking setTimeInterval only on button click

```js
window.onload = loadScript();
function loadScript() {
document.getElementById("popUpButton").onclick = function() {
setInterval(myTimerUp, 1000);
}
var count1=0; 
var counter1;
function myTimerUp() {  
count1=count1+1;
  if (count1 == 100) {
     clearInterval(counter);
     return;
  }
 document.getElementById("timerUp").innerHTML="This pop-up is running from "+ count1 + " secs"; // watch for spelling
}
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="popUpButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exModal1button">Pop-up manual trigger </button>
<span id="timerUp"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count1=0; 
var counter1=setInterval(myTimerUp, 1000)
```

Since these lines are not defined inside any function, they will execute when js file loads.

You can modify code as follows:-

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exModal1button" onclick="startTimer()">Pop-up manual trigger </button>
```

JS code :-

```
var count1=0; 
var counter1;

function startTimer(){
  if(counter1) clearInterval(counter1) // to clear interval if in case you closed modal before count1 reaches 100 and reopen model again (clearInterval should have been called when modal closes)
  count1 = 0;
  counter1=setInterval(myTimerUp, 1000);
}

function myTimerUp(){
  count1=count1+1;
  if (count1 == 100)
    clearInterval(counter1);
  else
    document.getElementById("timerUp").innerHTML="This pop-up is running from "+ count1 + " secs"; // watch for spelling
}
```

Comment: happy to help :)